# Usage of the indefinite article in "different choice of a nail would result in"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I am choosing (say) a nail of one or another type.

Should I say

1. "a different choice of **a** nail would result in ..."; or
2. "a different choice of nail would result in ..."?

Comment: It might not make any difference, but by "nail" do you mean the thing on you fingers and toes,  or the metal spike used in woodworking?

Comment: Shouldn't it be, "...choice of a different nail..."?  The confusion is what is different; nail(s) or  choice?

Comment: @JamesK Metal spike.

Comment: @RamPillai Both are different. As I said in my question, a different choice will imply a choice of a nail of another type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“A different choice of [noun]” is correct. No article needed or allowed.

While “a different [noun]” may appear to have the same meaning, inserting “choice of” emphasizes having other options. For instance, I assume you mean other sizes or types of nails are available to choose from, which may be better suited to your need, rather than just several identical nails.